# How can I route to a page any time no route is available?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to make a simple page with a back button for the odd case that a user enters a url to a page there is not route for.

For instance, the route for `foo` is:

```
resources :foos, :except => [:index]
```

The user enters:

```
mysite.com/foos
```

I want to display a page that says "This page doesn't exist" and a back button.

Where do I put the html.erb file and how to I account for that in routes.rb?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end of your routes.rb write:

```
match '*path', :controller => 'some_controller', :action => 'some_action'
```

or

```
match '*path' => 'some_controller#some_action'
```

Source:

> [rails handle 404 with url redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233657/rails-handle-404-with-url-redirect)

Answer (score 1):

In the production mode, the `404.html` in the `/public` folder of your Rails Application will be renderd for a Routing Error instead of displaying the error message.

Comment: No you cann't. But he only wants a 404 page which displays a message and a back button.

Answer (score 1):

As per my knowledge you have two ways to do this:

1. If you would like to capture errors like (404,500..etc.,) use [rescue_from](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods.html) in ActionController. Otherwise if you just want to edit the default error pages, edit the 500.html and 404.html files in {Rails.root}/public

**Example:** [How to properly render custom 404 and 500 pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9239803/how-to-properly-render-custom-404-and-500-pages)

2.[Custom Error Page - Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4525715/custom-error-page-ruby-on-rails)

Answer (score 0):

When a client's request can not be found in the server, a 404 redirect is made. To costumize the 404 page, simply change it in public/404.html